# Login to website using urllib instead of http.client

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, post, urllib

I am trying to login to a website using `urllib` in Python using the following code:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
payload = urllib.parse.urlencode({"username": "USERNAME-HERE",
                                  "password": "PASSWORD-HERE",
                                  "redirect": "index.php",
                                  "sid": "",
                                  "login": "Login"}).encode("utf-8")
request = urllib.request.Request("https://osu.ppy.sh/forum/ucp.php?mode=login", payload, headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()

# print the HTML after the request
print(bytes(str(data), "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape"))
```

I know that a common suggestion is to just use the Requests library, and I have tried this, but I specifically want to know how to do this without using Requests.

The behavior I am looking for can be replicated with the following code that successfully logs in to the site using `http.client`:

```
import urllib.parse
import http.client
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
payload = urllib.parse.urlencode({"username": "USERNAME-HERE",
                                  "password": "PASSWORD-HERE",
                                  "redirect": "index.php",
                                  "sid": "",
                                  "login": "Login"})
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("osu.ppy.sh")
conn.request("POST", "/forum/ucp.php?mode=login", payload, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()

# print the HTML after the request
print(bytes(str(data), "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape"))
```

It seems to me that the `urllib` code is not "delivering" the payload, while the `http.client` code is.

I seem to be able to "deliver" the payload, as providing a faulty password and username warrants a response from the server, but providing a correct username and password seems to have no effect.

Any insights? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I tried your code to run and i get the expected result (You have specified an incorrect password...). It means the payload is delivered. What do you get as response if you fill the right username/password?

Comment: @Qeek I also see the behavior you are mentioning, however when a correct username and password are given the site is still acting like I have not logged in ("Welcome, guest!" instead of "Welcome, <username>!"). Perhaps the login is not persisting after the initial payload delivery? Do I need to be using cookies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a cookie jar and take out the headers as they are not needed with `urllib`:

```
import http.cookiejar
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))

payload = urllib.parse.urlencode({"username": "USERNAME-HERE",
                                  "password": "PASSWORD-HERE",
                                  "redirect": "index.php",
                                  "sid": "",
                                  "login": "Login"}).encode("utf-8")
response = opener.open("https://osu.ppy.sh/forum/ucp.php?mode=login", payload)
data = response.read()

# print the HTML after the request
print(bytes(str(data), "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape"))
```